# MVC Multiple Databases in one single domain model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multiple-databases, domain-model

I am writting an app based on Steve Sanderson's Pro Asp .Net MVC Framework, which uses a data modeling like described on Sports Store app on that book. My app works well, I use Castle project as IOC but I have two databases. The first one stores many kind of data and my clients information. The second one stores only medical data of each client. I need to create a class that returns data in clients table, located on database 1 and medical information of each client stored on database 2.

Below are my code:

My connectionstrings on web.config:

```
<add name="CNRConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CNR;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=@#@@@!" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

<add name="CNRpeConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=pe;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=@#@@@!" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

My new class (just data, no table conection):

```
namespace DomainModel.Entities
{
    public class ImprimePeriodoPaciente
    {
        public int CodConsulta { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataConsulta { get; set; }
        public string Evolucao { get; set; }
        public int CodProfissional1 { get; set; }
        public int CodPaciente1 { get; set; }
        public string NomeProfissional { get; set; } //receives data from other db
        public string NomePaciente { get; set; } //receives data from other db
        public int CodProcedimento { get; set; }
        public bool TagConsulta { get; set; }
        public int? TagConsulta2 { get; set; } 
        public DateTime di { get; set; }
        public DateTime df { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my concrete and interface from domainmodel:

```
public  class SqlConsultasRepository:IConsultasRepository
    {
     private Table<Consulta> consultasTabela;
     private Table<TEvolucao> tEvolucaoTabela;
     private Table<Paciente> pacientesTabela;
     private Table<Funcionario> funcionariosTabela;

     public SqlConsultasRepository(string connectionString)
     {
         consultasTabela = (new DataContext(connectionString)).GetTable<Consulta>();
         tEvolucaoTabela = (new DataContext(connectionString)).GetTable<TEvolucao>();
         pacientesTabela = (new DataContext(connectionString)).GetTable<Paciente>();
         funcionariosTabela = (new DataContext(connectionString)).GetTable<Funcionario>();
     }


        public IQueryable<ImprimePeriodoPaciente> Prontuarios            { 
            get
            { 
                return
                    (
                       from c in consultasTabela
                       join p in pacientesTabela on c.CodPaciente1 equals p.CodigoPaciente //my doom
                       join f in funcionariosTabela on c.CodProfissional1 equals f.CodigoFuncionario //my doom
                       select new ImprimePeriodoPaciente
                       {
                           CodConsulta=c.CodConsulta,
                           DataConsulta=c.DataConsulta,
                           Evolucao=c.Evolucao,
                           NomeProfissional= f.NomeFuncionario, //my doom
                           NomePaciente=p.NomePaciente, //my doom
                           CodProfissional1=c.CodProfissional1,
                           CodPaciente1 = c.CodPaciente1
                       }
                   );
            }

        }
```

The code is marked with 'my doom' to show where the problem occurs.... I need to create a connectionString reference to the other database because this tables are not in current database specified by connectionString variable. I am getting error saying that the data are not from same datacontext (or shomething like that).

So, could you help?

Comment: I have read Pro Asp.Net MVC 3 and I recommend to steer away from the Sports Store application example. It is the most insane, pathologically over-engineered and unrealistic code I have ever seen in my life.
Steve Sanderson writes frameworks and books, but these are not real life applications and when the all the examples don't stick together 
it is not a big deal.

Comment: Well, I know his way of life seems tough but I don´t think i´ts time to reingeneer my app, cause I don´t have this time... Tnx for your advice.... the next apps won´t get this way.

Answer (score 0):

Got my way through it based on this post:

http://dotnetprogrammingtipsbymuhil.blogspot.com.br/2009/12/query-contains-references-to-items.html

For those who get on same problem, follow above post steps.

Im my project I've created  an interface to a concrete method that takes separated data from each database and put them on separated lists, as follows:

```
namespace DomainModel.Concrete
{
    public class SqlImprimePeriodoPacientesRepository : IImprimePeriodoPacientesRepository
    {
    private static string cConexao = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CNR;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=23092000";
    private static string cConexao2 = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PE;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=23092000";

    private IConsultasRepository cRepository = new SqlConsultasRepository(cConexao2);
    private IPacientesRepository pRepisotory = new SqlPacientesRepository(cConexao);
    private IFuncionariosRepository fRepository = new SqlFuncionariosRepository(cConexao);

    public IQueryable<ImprimePeriodoPaciente> ImprimePeriodoProntuarios//(int? codpac, DateTime? di, DateTime? df)
    {
        get
        {
            var consultas =
                (
                    from c in cRepository.Consultas
                    select new
                    {
                        c.cdf,
                        c.cdi,
                        c.CodConsulta,
                        c.CodPaciente1,
                        c.CodProcedimento,
                        c.CodProfissional1,
                        c.DataConsulta,
                        c.df,
                        c.di,
                        c.Evolucao,
                        c.TagConsulta,
                        c.TagConsulta2
                    }
                )
                .ToList();

            var pacientes =
                (
                    from p in pRepisotory.Pacientes
                    select new
                    {
                        p.CodigoPaciente,
                        p.NomePaciente
                    }
                )
                .ToList();

            var funcionarios =
                (
                    from f in fRepository.Funcionarios
                    select new
                    {
                        f.CodigoFuncionario,
                        f.NomeFuncionario
                    }
                )
                .ToList();

            var result =
                (
                    from c in consultas
                    join p in pacientes on c.CodPaciente1 equals p.CodigoPaciente
                    join f in funcionarios on c.CodProfissional1 equals f.CodigoFuncionario
                    select new ImprimePeriodoPaciente
                    {
                        CodConsulta = c.CodConsulta,
                        DataConsulta = c.DataConsulta,
                        Evolucao = c.Evolucao,
                        NomeProfissional = f.NomeFuncionario,
                        NomePaciente = p.NomePaciente,
                        CodProfissional1 = c.CodProfissional1,
                        CodPaciente1 = c.CodPaciente1
                    }
                ).ToList();


            return result.AsQueryable();
        }
    }
}
}
```

That method did the job on the Domain´s Model side, so the rest resides on dealing with the results.

Hope this help someone!